# Accessibility tag missing from Arts & Crafts site

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I would like to talk about the sort of art that would help kids and people with autism or autism spectrum type problems (by allowing them to select a picture from a set of pictures, to describe their emotional state or the state of the emotion of the person they are thinking about). However, the accessibility tag seems to be missing from this site. Would someone be able to create it for me please.

Furthermore, I would like to know what other tags could be used in this context. Thank you for your suggestions, and for the inclusion of an accessibility tag.

Answer (score 3):

We don't create a tag until a question exists that can use it. Please feel free to ask the question even if the tags aren't exactly what you might imagine yet -- and then as a community we can add what would be appropriate :)

Comment: And at [150 reputation](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you can add new tags yourself! Although the community will still quality-check everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the gist would be applicable to other specific requests.

In general, tags serve certain purposes.  Mainly, they attract the appropriate people to answer the question and serve as common search terms for people with a similar requirement.  Tags can also add important context to limit or focus the question.

The subject of accessibility involves specialized knowledge that isn't within the purview of the site.  So it wouldn't be on-topic to ask a question where you're looking for site members to bring that expertise (even if, by coincidence, some members might have the relevant knowledge).  However, that doesn't mean nothing about the project would be on-topic here.

Someone with specialized knowledge could help describe ideas, objectives, and requirements for projects that would be helpful for people with specific needs.  That part of things isn't within the scope of the site.

But that could lead to a project based on those conceptual efforts.  If all of the requirements can be met with the usual methods and materials, there wouldn't need to be a question here.  But if meeting those requirements presented a specific challenge, how to accomplish the results might be a good question for the site.  In that case, the tags would relate to the project and the issues to be solved here.  Why the project came to exist can add some interesting context to the body of the question, but isn't relevant for tagging.